# First field retrieving in case of new delimiter

Tags: unix, delimiter, cut

I have a first record in a Unix file like this, from which I would like to retrieve CST_ID into a variable.

```
CST_ID||@||CST_NAME||@||CST_ADD||@||CST_ACC
```

How can I do it?  I am using this.

```
head -1 test.txt | awk -F '||@||' '{print $1}'
```

However, it is giving `CST_ID||` as output, but I need only `CST_ID`.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Hi , i am using this. head -1 test.txt | awk -F '||@||' '{print $1}'....however it is giving CST_ID|| as ouput. but i need only CST_ID

Comment: @user6911877: In future, please edit the question to add the extra information.  This time, I've done it for you, but you should do it yourself in future (and you should include your best effort without being prompted to add it — it often tells us a lot about what might be an appropriate answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut`, like for the tag you added.

```
robert@habanero:~$ cat input 
CST_ID||@||CST_NAME||@||CST_ADD||@||CST_ACC

robert@habanero:~$ cut -d '|' -f 1 < input
CST_ID
```

The `-d` defines the delimiter, here a pipe. It needs to be in single quotes so that the shell does not interpret it. The `-f` specifies which field you want, in this case the first one.

Combine this with `head` (or `tail`) if you just want to do this for a certain number of lines.

Capture this in a variable like this (assuming bash):

```
var=$(cut -d '|' -f 1 < input)
```

Comment: Hi, when we use cut -d 'I' , are we not specifying delimiter as | ? however delimiter here is ||@||. i would like to use cut -d '||@||' .But shell is giving me syntax error.

Comment: Why do you want to use '||@||' as delimiter? If you only care for the CST_ID part, using '|' is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sample input:

```
    cat sample
    CST_ID||@||CST_NAME||@||CST_ADD||@||CST_ACC
```

Solution: `grep` from start of the line till first `||` is seen.  `-m` is used to exit after first match.
`awk` : `||` is set as delimiter and first field is printed. `NR==1` is to limit search to first field.

```
grep -m1 -oP '^.*?(?=\|\|)' sample
CST_ID
awk -F'\\|\\|' 'NR==1{print $1}' sample
CST_ID
awk -F'\\|\\|' 'NR==1{NF=1}1' sample
CST_ID
```